# How to provide a link for the logo in Quarto revealjs presentations?

Tags: yaml, quarto

With Quarto we can provide a logo for presentation slides as following:

in the `_quarto.yml` file:

```yaml
format:
    revealjs:
        logo: image.png
```

Is there a way to make it a linked logo, so that clicking it redirects to e.g. a Homepage?

In markdown we can insert linked images as e.g. `[![image](image.png)](https://stackoverflow.com)`, however this seems not to work in the yaml file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Updated Answer:

Now you can easily link the footer logo using the quarto extension [`reveal-header`](https://github.com/shafayetShafee/reveal-header) (v 1.2.7) which provides an option `footer-logo-link` now.

So first install the extension using `quarto add shafayetShafee/reveal-header` and then,

**presentation.qmd**

```
---
title: Testing
format:
    revealjs:
      logo: quarto.png
      footer-logo-link: "https://quarto.org"
filters:
  - reveal-header
---


## Quarto
```

---

#### Old Answer:

You can write a JavaScript function to take the rendered logo image and then nest it within an `a` tag with the desired hyperlink.

**logo-hyperlink.html**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  function hyperlink_logo() {
    let logo = document.querySelector('img.slide-logo');
    const logo_cloned = logo.cloneNode(true);
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    // -----------------------------------------------------------
    // set the link for the logo here in `link.href` within quotes
    link.href = 'https://stackoverflow.com';
    // -----------------------------------------------------------
    link.target = '_blank';
    link.appendChild(logo_cloned);
    logo.replaceWith(link);
  };
  
  window.document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    hyperlink_logo();
  });
</script>
```

*Set the link enclosed with quotes for the logo as the value of `link.href`*. And then include this html file to the qmd file.

**presentation.qmd**

```markdown
---
title: Testing
format:
    revealjs:
      logo: SO.png
include-after-body: logo-hyperlink.html
---


## Quarto
```

Comment: awesome, thanks! I even thought there would be an easier solution, but this works.

Comment: @jenswiesehahn, I have a plan to implement this as a feature to the extension [`reveal-header`](https://github.com/shafayetShafee/reveal-header) so that it simply could be done from the yaml section. I will let you know if I do that.